# Pc games have started to lag and make crackling sounds

Tags: audio, video, gaming, lag

My pc worked fine a few days ago but suddenly my pc games have started to lag a bit and make popping crackling sounds especially when the videos and cutscenes play.Google chrome 1080p60 videos also lag and make the same noises as the games but every other browser works fine in 1080p60 videos (microsoft edge, firefox).I've updated to the latest nvidia drivers & sound drivers,downgraded to beta drivers,temp inside is also fine,I've dusted everything & re positioned the ram sticks,defragmented drives and I haven't overclocked my cpu.The games and videos still work but they're now choppy and I can't find where the problem is coming from.

PC specs:

```
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393)
             Language: English
  System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.                
         System Model: Dell DXP061                  
                 BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 2.5.3 
            Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU  X3230  @ 2.66GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8126MB RAM
            Page File: 3439MB used, 12878MB available             
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650
   Manufacturer: NVIDIA
      Chip type: GeForce GTX 650
 Display Memory: 5057 MB
```

Comment: Try downgrading to previous Windows version, if you have the time.
My CS:GO got laggy and the only significant thing happened was a big Windows Update to version 14393.